# Trying to view website after IP change in Chrome

Tags: apache, google-chrome, ssl, ip, browser-cache

I've recently changed the IP on a website as I added a SSL certificate.

Now going back to view the site I get the "Apache is working on your cPanel and WHM Server" message.

```
http://domain.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi
```

This looks like a cache issue with Chrome as I can see the page on other devices and when using Incognito browsing in Chrome also in other browsers on the same PC.

I've cleared every history entry in Chrome from my domain and also removed cookies. I still can't view my site. It has been 6 days since I changed the IP.

Any ideas? I'd rather be using Chrome by the way .

Thanks for any suggestions :)

Comment: Please provide the real URL for the server.

Comment: The real URL will take you to the site more than likely with no problems www.tshirtsofoz.com.au The issue appears to be with Chrome cache. Well that's all I can find on the net anyway.

Comment: No more suggestions? It's weird as jww has stated he gets a 301 error when browsing to domain/wp-admin however this page I can access and successfully login :S

Answer (score 0):

> The real URL will take you to the site more than likely with no problems www.tshirtsofoz.com.au

It looks like a configuration issue at the server. I don't believe its at the client. Below, the point of interest is the response:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Date: Wed, 27 Aug 2014 08:01:52 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.25 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.25 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_bwlimited/1.4
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.21
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
X-Pingback: https://tshirtsofoz.com.au/xmlrpc.php
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=9690b2302154849c9f0f4b1583cd6175; path=/
Location: https://tshirtsofoz.com.au/wp-admin/
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

And I get no response when following the redirect (i.e., `GET /wp-admin/ ...`). If I follow *without* the trailing slash, I get:

```
$ echo -e "GET /wp-admin HTTPS/1.1\r\n" | openssl s_client -connect www.tshirtsofoz.com.au:443 -ign_eof
...

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Wed, 27 Aug 2014 08:07:45 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.25 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.25 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_bwlimited/1.4
Location: https://tshirtsofoz.com.au/wp-admin/
Content-Length: 386
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://tshirtsofoz.com.au/wp-admin/">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.25 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.25 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_bwlimited/1.4 Server at tshirtsofoz.com.au Port 443</address>
</body></html>
closed
```

Also, OpenSSL 0.9.8e has a number of vulnerablities.

---

```
$ echo -e "GET / HTTPS/1.1\r\n" | openssl s_client -connect www.tshirtsofoz.com.au:443 -ign_eof
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 C = US, ST = Illinois, L = Chicago, O = "Trustwave Holdings, Inc.", CN = "Trustwave Organization Validation CA, Level 2", emailAddress = ca@trustwave.com
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/CN=tshirtsofoz.com.au/O=T-shirts of Oz/L=Adelaide/ST=SA/C=AU
   i:/C=US/ST=Illinois/L=Chicago/O=Trustwave Holdings, Inc./CN=Trustwave Organization Validation CA, Level 2/emailAddress=ca@trustwave.com
 1 s:/C=US/ST=Illinois/L=Chicago/O=Trustwave Holdings, Inc./CN=Trustwave Organization Validation CA, Level 2/emailAddress=ca@trustwave.com
   i:/C=US/O=SecureTrust Corporation/CN=SecureTrust CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/CN=tshirtsofoz.com.au/O=T-shirts of Oz/L=Adelaide/ST=SA/C=AU
issuer=/C=US/ST=Illinois/L=Chicago/O=Trustwave Holdings, Inc./CN=Trustwave Organization Validation CA, Level 2/emailAddress=ca@trustwave.com
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 3217 bytes and written 506 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1
    Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA
    Session-ID: 94A2EBDFF8EBA3B60B0CBCE497B21FB5753DD07FABFBD21CC2642C2F0665EE34
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 74BBCA1A44D5A8AAD5FD916C761E349B7FAD876D35B03AB499E20ADBC8170C643917DAF414D8AAE46D5574349DBCBB07
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1409126533
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
---
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Date: Wed, 27 Aug 2014 08:01:52 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.25 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.25 OpenSSL/0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 mod_bwlimited/1.4
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.21
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
X-Pingback: https://tshirtsofoz.com.au/xmlrpc.php
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=9690b2302154849c9f0f4b1583cd6175; path=/
Location: https://tshirtsofoz.com.au/wp-admin/
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

closed
```

Comment: Hmmm a bit over my head but thanks for the reply @jww. I'm going to have to look into this issue further with what you've suggested. It's weird I've never had this issue pop up before.